# unity android - build and run game on pc

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, and I am trying to make a simple product, in the meanwhile with tutorials I found in the web.

though I am faceing a problem - I can't figure out why I can't build and run the game on the pc.  when I hit the build and run button, for android, it tells me that there is no device connected, so it can't compile, though, I just want to test the game on my pc, so I don't want to connect my phone device, I want to do all the test on the pc. isn't it possible? I can't check the game on the pc?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing the Play button above the scene should run it locally.

Otherwise, check **File -> Build Settings** and change platform to PC.

If you're trying to test any Android code on your local machine, you'll still need to connect a device or spin up a Android emulator.